# Dynamic date filter in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want set a dynamic date filter in a table `DateTime.LocalNow()`, so that everytime I refresh the query it won't import data beyond current date.
I've already set a fixed filter `"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each [#"Mnd År - Copy"] <= #date(2023, 12, 1))`, but how do I manipulate this filter to become a dynamic filter by implementing `DateTime.LocalNow()`

The table looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date.From(...)` to convert DateTime to Date. So try:

```
"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each [#"Mnd År - Copy"] <= Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) )
```